# Why does adding \usepackage{tikz} break my document?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using TeXmaker.  When I try to typeset anything containing \usepackage{tikz} the MiKTeX package manager pops up, I click "Yes" to install.  After a few seconds it flashes something like "Sorry, pdflatex did not succeed.  Hopefully the log file ...".  The log file is blank.  Any hints on how to proceed?  Every other package I've used has auto-installed just fine.  Minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Hello World.
\end{document}
```

Comment: try to install in the miktex console.

Comment: clicking the "update all" in the miktex console and then rebooting seemed to do the trick.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question has been solved in a comment